# UFW/Iptables: Allow response to http(s) requests but block everything else

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'd like to block everything outgoing from my server while still allowing responses to incoming  http/https requests.

Some examples:

User calls my server using his browser (https://myserver.example.org/test.html)
Firewall should allow a response and server should deliver test.html to user.

Application on my server tries to connect to https://badguy.example.org/test.html
Firewall should deny this outgoing request because badguy.example.org didn't request anything from my server.

I don't want that to be based on IPs or IP ranges. Just if server is contacted from an ip, it is allowed to respond. If he hasn't been contacted by this ip before, it is not allowed to send anything there.

Is this possibe using ufw or iptables? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is the flag *`--state ESTABLISHED`* in the OUTPUT chain which allow only ESTABLISHED connections not new ones.

(OPTIONAL) Allow login via SSH for administration's tasks,

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Allow HTTP traffic

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Allow HTTPS traffic

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443-m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 443-m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Block outgoing http/https requests originated from your server.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Comment: It works. Many thanks!